what is the basis that there is no olah and fire burning on the altar any more?
BH
Hi so I heard that the fire had to be constantly on and was even on during the time in the desert and eventually on the 17th of Tamuz during the times of the Romans, the perpetual fire and the tamid were canceled.
So what is the basis of this: Who decreed the ceasing of the Tamid and the fire to be stopped?
Also, how can the fire be stopped if it says Leviticus 6:6 "A perpetual fire shall be kept burning on the altar, it shall not to go out"?
Correct me if I'm wrong: Is the reason we don't have the fire and tamid right now because a prophet can annul a mitzvah only temporarily and not forever since Mashiach is going to come soon besiata deshmaya and reinstate the avodat hamikdash?

The perpetual fire was supposed to be a small candle on the side of Mizbeach from which they made the fire on the altar and the menora

didnt the fire of the mizbeach also have to be on though the whole day constantly burning?

@YDJ You are confused. The perpetual fire was one of the fires on the mizbeach, see Maseches Yoma.

No altar, therefore the whole thing is not relevant.

@N.T. Yes, Yoma 45b, that's what I meant eish tamid - on the mizbeach, ner tamid - on the menorah (Tamid 6:1).
